# Can't include file using absolute path in PHP

Tags: php, include

I have a website is located in `/proj/hcr/` (the Apache DocumentRoot is /proj). I am trying to include a file using an absolute path, but it says that the file does not exist even though it does. The line of code is as follows: `include_once '/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php';`

Here is the directory structure for the file I am trying to include

[image: directory]

Comment: so um ... `include_once '/proj/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php';`

Comment: think about the question...Apache's DocumentRoot has been set to /proj/, so giving it /proj/ won't work because it would be `/proj/proj/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php` would it not?

Comment: your confusing server and webserver, the path php uses is the servers path, not the web server

Comment: either way it doesn't work it gives me a problem loading page

Comment: what's the exact error message? what are the file\path permissions set to?

Comment: it works when I give it a relative path, but not an absolute path, I need to give it an absolute path because I am including it in files that aren't in the same directory as it. the permissions have nothing to do with it. the error im getting is this `The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.`

Answer (score 1):

Your question title says that **include with absolute path** doesn't work in PHP, but in your question I read:

> I am trying to include a file using a **relative path**, but it says that the file does not exist even though it does. The line of code is as follows: `include_once '/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php';`

I am assuming you are trying to include file with `'/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php'` (which is supposed to be an absolute path).

Absolute path doesn't start from root directory by default,so `'/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php'` is not an absolute path since it lacks the path to the root directory.  You need to provide the **full path to the file on the machine**. For example , absolute path on windows machine (using xampp as a web server,installed on C) would be:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php
```

You should use the following code:

```
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/hcr/spaces-api/spaces.php';
```

So , `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` will give you **path to the root directory** and you can then concatenate it with path to file in root directory.